# Proper return type for Redux action

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux, react-redux, tsc

This typing sort of works, but for some reason the promise that dispatch() is supposed to return is not defined:

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

So instead of using `ThunkAction<any,any,any,any>` is there a better type I can use perhaps? Or maybe `ThunkAction` is the wrong type altogether?

Here is all my code:

```
import {ThunkAction, ThunkDispatch} from 'redux-thunk';
const {setLanguage} = require('redux-polyglot');
import {CMError} from '../shared/cm-error';
import {receiveCurrentUser} from './login';

export const signup = (
  email: string,
  pwd: string,
  fullName: string
): ThunkAction<any, any, any, any> => {

  return (dispatch) => {

    return fetchFromApi(`/cp/users`, {
      method: 'POST',
      body: {
        email: email,
        password: pwd,
        name: fullName
      }
    }).then(
      ([resp, json]) => {

        if (resp.status === 200) {
          return dispatch(receiveCurrentUser(json));
        }
      })
    );
  };
};
```

I don't see a mention of this in the react-redux TS docs:
https://react-redux.js.org/using-react-redux/static-typing

Answer (score 0):

That's because thunks are not part of React-Redux - they're a separate middleware that's added to the Redux core.

We cover typing thunks in [the Redux core docs "Usage with TypeScript" page](https://redux.js.org/recipes/usage-with-typescript#usage-with-redux-thunk), and in [the Redux Toolkit "Advanced Tutorial" page](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/tutorials/advanced-tutorial).

Specifically for your case, the first generic argument to `ThunkAction` is the expected return type of the thunk.  So, it should look something like:

```
ThunkAction<Promise<SomeValue>, RootState, unknown, Action<String>>
```

and that should be applied to the definition of `getCurrentUser()`.

Comment: thanks what/where is the string arg in `Action<string>`?  Is Action the same as ThunkAction from redux-thunk library?

Comment: looks like there is both `{ThunkAction, Action} from 'redux-thunk'`